# setFullscreen true for ipad landscape jwplayer7

Tags: javascript, ipad, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I'm using jwplayer 7 javascript version. It works nice. Just one thing when video starts to play on portrait it should stay on its own area but on landscape it should go to fullscreen.

This code works perfectly on htc, samsung phones but on IPAD isn't working. How can I make it work also on IPAD?

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 480 && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1100) {  
        var getState = playerInstance.getState();
        if(getState == 'playing' || getState != 'idle' || getState != 'buffering' || getState != 'paused' || getState != 'undefined'){
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); 
        }else if (getState != 'playing' && getState == 'paused'){
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(false); 
        }
    }else {
        var getState = playerInstance.getState();
        if(getState != 'playing' || getState == 'paused' || getState == 'idle' || getState == 'buffering'){
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(false); 
        } 
        if(getState == 'undefined'){
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(false); 
        } 
        if(getState == 'playing'){
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(false); 
        }
        if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))) {
            jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?